# Unity - Get Bytes array from Image

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, byte

I am wondering how I am able to get an array of Bytes from a standard PNG image.

The purpose is to be able to send information from Unity, to cloudstore.

Thank you!

Comment: [ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html) the example is there in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This link help you to this:
[ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html)

```
public Texture2D tex;

public void Convert()
{
    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    
    // do something..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: realized this might not work for the question, because it looks like OP is trying to convert a unity texture to a byte array, instead of a file.

Just use `File.ReadAllBytes` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-6.0).

Example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class example
{
   public byte[] ex(string path) 
   {
       byte​[] ​imageData​ ​=​ ​File​.​ReadAllBytes​(​path​);
       return imageData;
   }
}
```